# Allocating more RAM to Integrated Intel HD Graphics

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, battery

I am concerned about power consumption on my [Asus laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X55A/).

I have allocated 512MB (maximum allowed) of RAM to the graphics card, and I wanted to know if the more you allocate the more power it consumes? I really need the battery to last as much as possible.

Also, any other tips for reducing power consumption is welcome.

**PS1:** *The RAM is 1600Mhz, not 1333Mhz as stated on ASUS's website.*

**PS2:** *I'm not playing any kind of games ever when on battery.*

Comment: Have you tried to lower the memory reserved for the graphics card to see if it makes any difference?  If your not tasking the graphics card then its not using the current memory anyways so lowering it won't make a difference.

Comment: You act like I should have known that.  I posted my statement a full hour and half before you provided that information.  If you can't try different things I won't bother giving you different thing that might work its simply not worth my time.

Comment: Note that the more RAM you allocate it, the worse its performance, paradoxically enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have data to back this up, but I suspect that it does not make much difference either way, since if the GPU is not using that memory, the CPU will. Other tips for reducing the load on the battery and increasing run time: disable WiFi, disable Bluetooth, turn down screen brightness, turn down volume on speakers, switch to an SSD, and set a short idle time before the computer goes to sleep.

The only way to know for sure if reducing shared memory will help is to benchmark it on your laptop under your working conditions, and see which way lasts longer or if it makes a difference at all.

Someone who knows better how the shared memory works maybe able to offer a more better opinion.